# Can openrdf-sesame recover the unseen data in openrdf-workbench?

Tags: sesame, openrdf

Somehow I found some of the repositories(`physics_base` for example) in workbench are missing, but when I searched into the data path `/.aduna/openrdf-sesame/repositories/physics_base`, I found the data still exist. 
[image]
So does this mean that there is a way to recover my data in workbench?
Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible. Just create a new repository of the same type in the workbench, open it once, shut down sesame, then copy over the contents of the directory to the data directory of your new repository.

It might even be possible to just create a repository of the same name and have it automatically pick up the existing data, but I can't test that right now (in a pub), so if you want to try that, make a backup first.